# A garbage character appears when using substr() on a Chinese language string

Tags: php, utf-8, substr, garbage

I am trying to get some character(s) from a Chinese string. But always a garbage character appears at the end.

How can I get some char from Chinese string?

Comment: Without telling you which programming language you're using, how do you expect us to help you? Chances are that you're splitting a UTF-8 or UTF-16 compound character into pieces, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using PHP:

when using non ascii character you should use the multibyte functions, in this case the function `mb_substr`. Remember to set the internal encoding to use through the `mb_internal_encoding` function.